# How to write a check constraint to verify if login is correct or not?

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation, check-constraints

I searched the internet for 2 days to find the answer and couldn't.

Basically I have this as a problem : "The login is composed of the first letter of the first name and the first 7 letters of the name (in lowercase) followed by two numbers."

My problem relies in the last 4 words "followed by two numbers". The first part I have done it correctly and it validates it, but i cant seem to find the answer to the problem specified above.

I tried doing something like this.

```
    CONSTRAINT ck_user_login CHECK
        (login LIKE SUBSTR(prenom,1, 1) || LOWER(SUBSTR(nom, 0, 7)) || '%[0-9]%')
```

But that does not seem to work.

All help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do it in two steps: first check *first and last name*, then check *digits*. Something like this:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE test
  2  (
  3     prenom   VARCHAR2 (10),
  4     nom      VARCHAR2 (10),
  5     login    VARCHAR2 (20)
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> ALTER TABLE test
  2     ADD CONSTRAINT ck_user_login CHECK
  3            (    SUBSTR (login, 1, LENGTH (login) - 2) LIKE
  4                    SUBSTR (prenom, 1, 1) || LOWER (SUBSTR (nom, 1, 7))
  5             AND REGEXP_LIKE (login, '\d{2}$'));

Table altered.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO test (prenom, nom, login) VALUES ('little', 'foot', 'lfoot23');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO test (prenom, nom, login) VALUES ('little', 'foot', 'lfootacd23');
INSERT INTO test (prenom, nom, login) VALUES ('little', 'foot', 'lfootacd23')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CK_USER_LOGIN) violated


SQL> INSERT INTO test (prenom, nom, login) VALUES ('little', 'foot', 'lfoot235');
INSERT INTO test (prenom, nom, login) VALUES ('little', 'foot', 'lfoot235')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CK_USER_LOGIN) violated


SQL> INSERT INTO test (prenom, nom, login) VALUES ('little', 'foot', 'lfoot23x');
INSERT INTO test (prenom, nom, login) VALUES ('little', 'foot', 'lfoot23x')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CK_USER_LOGIN) violated


SQL>
```

Comment: I like this thinking to split such tasks in two steps. Often, people try to put everything in as less steps and even as less characters as possible. Good SQL code is in my opinion not the shortest one, but the best readable (unless this causes bad performance).

Comment: I'm glad you like it, @Jonas. You're welcome, ppenguin.

Answer (score 0):

Two digits would be `'[0-9][0-9]'`, not `'%[0-9]%'`; however, the LIKE operstor does understand this. The best you can do with LIKE is to test whether there are two characters after the name

```sql
CONSTRAINT ck_user_login CHECK
   (login LIKE SUBSTR(prenom, 1, 1) || LOWER(SUBSTR(nom, 1, 7)) || '__')
```

Since the the login is of fixed length, there is no need to add the wildcard `%` which specifies that any characters can appear multiple times.

You must use `REGEXP_LIKE` for more complex patterns

```sql
CONSTRAINT ck_user_login CHECK (
   login LIKE SUBSTR(prenom, 1, 1) || LOWER(SUBSTR(nom, 1, 7)) || '__' AND
   REGEXP_LIKE( SUBSTR(login,-2), '[0-9][0-9]' )
)
```

I suggest not to compare the whole login with REGEXP, since then you would have to escape the name part if any characters conflict with special REGEXP characters.

Other SQL dialects allow for more complex LIKE operators like `Like P[A-F]###` in [Access](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/like-operator-b2f7ef03-9085-4ffb-9829-eef18358e931) for instance or character ranges `LIKE '[0-9]'` in [Transact-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: You can't use `[0-9][0-9]` with LIKE, since these are thought to be used with regexp.

Comment: That code expects that *two substrings* have - literally - a string `'[0-9][0-9]'` attached to the end, so - no, that won't work.

Comment: That's Oracle, Olivier. There's no RIGHT function there.

Comment: You can use `SUBSTR` with a negative length instead. ( I saw a RIGHT function in an Oracle doc, but that one was probably for another language than PL/SQL.)